# Unexpected results for a nested query with multiple _TABLE_SUFFIX conditions

Tags: google-bigquery

Consider the following query (standard syntax):

```sql
WITH
  v AS (
  SELECT
    _TABLE_SUFFIX AS y,
    *
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod*`
  WHERE
    _TABLE_SUFFIX > '2000' )
SELECT
  y,
  COUNT(1) c
FROM
  v
WHERE
  y IN ('2016',
    '2017')
GROUP BY
  y
```

I was expecting it to return two rows:

```
2016 4292866     
2017 3683760
```

However, **only the first one is returned**. I find it very weird. Is there any reason for this?

If you remove `WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX > '2000'` from the subquery, both rows are returned as expected. Also, if you remove `2016` from the list at the bottom, the single row for `2017` is returned correctly.

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: this is a bug! reporting internally... thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

One can work it around by casting `_table_suffix` to integer
Credit goes to [Przemek Iwańczak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7256685/przemyslaw-iwanczak).

```sql
WITH
  v AS (
  SELECT
    _TABLE_SUFFIX AS y,
    *
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod*`
  WHERE CAST(_TABLE_SUFFIX as INT64) > 2000
    )
SELECT
  y,
  COUNT(1) c
FROM
  v
WHERE
  y IN ('2016',
    '2017')
GROUP BY
  y
```